# Save text file in UTF-8 encoding using cmd.exe

Tags: windows, encoding, utf-8, cmd

Is it possible to save a text file in UTF-8 encoding using Windows' command line `cmd.exe`?

Current I'm creating the text file using command redirection operators:

```
C:\Windows\system32\ipconfig /all >> output.log
```

I start with `>` to get a new file and then I use `>>` to append more information.

Comment: If you are using I/O redirection operators, then it's not up to the shell what the character encoding of the data is. It's up to the command whose output is redirected. If that command produces valid UTF-8, that's what will end up in the file.

Comment: Imo `ipconfig`  uses "Unicode".

Comment: It doesn't.  Like all console mode programs, it generates text in the default 8-bit code page encoding that's active for the console.  Which you change to utf-8 with chcp 65001.  You still won't get a BOM.

Comment: `cmd /u /c "ipconfig /all" >>  output.log`  ???

Answer (score 52):

The default encoding for command prompt is Windows-1252. Change the code page (chcp command) to 65001 (UTF-8) first and then run your command.

```
chcp 65001
C:\Windows\system32\ipconfig /all >> output.log
```

Change it back to default when done.

```
chcp 1252
```

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) are some other code that may be useful

Comment: 1252 might not be the default codepage. The OEM codepage is the default.

Answer (score 5):

As the existing answer says, in a batch file, you can use the [`chcp` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp)

```
chcp 65001 > nul
some_command > file
```

---

But if you are using the [`cmd.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) from its command line, e.g. to execute a user-defined command, you can use this syntax:

```
cmd.exe /c chcp 65001 > nul & cmd.exe /c some_command > file
```