# Can't show certain UTF-8 characters in android webview

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8, webview

I know this problem has been documented elsewhere but the solutions don't seem to work for me.  Other similar questions:

[Android WebView with garbled UTF-8 characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933069/android-webview-with-garbled-utf-8-characters)

[Android WebView UTF-8 not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312643/android-webview-utf-8-not-showing)

I'm essentially trying to show the minus/plus character (∓) in an android webview.  I tested several other characters 'around' the minus plus character in the UTF-8 table but some of them didn't work either

Here is the java im using:

```
final WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
w.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");        

InputStream is;
try {
    is = getAssets().open("test5.html");

    int size = is.available();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();

    String str = new String(buffer);

    w.loadData(str, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```

Here is the html test5.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    char: ∓ <br/>
    char: ∔ <br/>
    char: ∕ <br/>
    char: ∖ <br/>
    char: ∗ <br/>
    char: ∘ <br/>
</body>
```

The only characters that show up are the "∕" and "∗".  I've also tried

```
w.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///doesnotmatter", str, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

with no success.  I'm not too familiar with the input stream thing so I don't know if there's something wrong there.  Please help, its taken me awhile =\

-Teneth

Answer (score 0):

When you call *loadData()*, pass the encoding as uppercase "UTF-8", because it is case sensitive and that's the standard representation according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDefaultTextEncodingName(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I tried "w.loadData(str, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8");"  but nothing changed.  I then also put caps in the "w.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");" but nothing changed. =\

Comment: Then [save your HTML file with UTF-8 encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598785/save-text-file-in-utf-8-encoding-using-cmd-exe). Perhaps even include [BOM](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to ensure its encoding is interpreted as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

use html codes for that characters in your html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
   char: &#8723;<br/>
   char: &#8724;<br/>
   char: &#8725;<br/>
   char: &#8726;<br/>
   char: &#8727;<br/>
   char: &#8728;<br/>
</body>
```